# error CS0234: The type or namespace name "EnrollmentViewModel'' does not exist in the namespace ''ContosoUniversity.ViewModels"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can not find a problem because everything looks fine.

error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EnrollmentViewModel' does not exist in the namespace 'ContosoUniversity.ViewModels' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

```
    Строка 29:     
Строка 30:     
Строка 31:     public class _Page_Views_Enrollment_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IEnumerable<ContosoUniversity.ViewModels.EnrollmentViewModel>> {
Строка 32:         
Строка 33: #line hidden
```

Viewmodel class-

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.ViewModels
{
    public class EnrollmentViewModel
    {
        public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public Grade? Grade { get; set; }

        public Course Course { get; set; }
        public Student Student { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Grade
    {
        A, B, C, D, F
    }
```

}

Comment: Do you have a class *EnrollmentViewModel* in your solution? In Visual Studio you should be able to type the name in the "Search Solution Explorer" box in the Solution Explorer - this will match based both on the file and/or class name. If the class does exist, what is its namespace?

Comment: namespace ContosoUniversity.ViewModels

Comment: Is the view model public? I.e. namespace ContosoUniversity.ViewModels { **public** class EnrollmentViewModel{ ... } } - if so, can you post the view model code? (Can remove properties - we just need the declaration itself)

Comment: Presumably in your code there is another closing curly brace after the *Grade* Enum? I.e public enum Grade { A, B, C, D, F } **}** - this would normally sit on the next line as the first character.

Comment: Sorry, but this is I forgot to put a closing curly here, but in program I have it, problem in something else!

Comment: Does the view model exist in the same project as the view? Do you need to add a reference from the project with the view to the project with the view model? Does the solution compile if you give the view a model of a IEnumerable of a primitive (built in) class - IEnumerable<string> say?

Comment: Have you managed to solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had similar issue recently. The solution to my problem was the namespace is defined differently in Model.cs where as it is specified differently in view. That could be the issue.